# Stored Procedure no Entity Framework sem modelo edmx

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tenho um projeto que utiliza o Entity Framework sem um modelo `edmx`, nós cadastramos as entidades de forma manual criamos uma classe e inserimos ela no contexto.

Alguém utiliza este formato e sabe como cadastrar uma *Stored Procedure* desta forma?

Comment: Sobre "cadastrar de forma manual", você quer dizer Code First?

Comment: Extato @GuilhermeJSantos... tinha esquecido como chamava...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A partir da versão 5 do Entity Framework existe uma maneira simples de executarmos uma *Stored Procedure* com base na instancia do `DbContext`, usando propriedade `DataBase`, veja:

```
using(MeuContexto context = new MeuContexto())
{
    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@idCliente", 1);     
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("sp_ExcluirCliente @idCliente", param);
}
```

Ou até mesmo executar Stored Procedures com retorno, cujo este retorno possa ser um entidade do seu contexto:

```
public List<Cliente> Clientes()
{
    using(MeuContexto context = new MeuContexto())
    {
        return context.Database.SqlQuery<Cliente>("exec sp_Clientes).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Complementando a informação acima:

Para executar uma stored procedure vc pode fazer conforme o código abaixo:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   try
  {
      SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[nome_da_procedure]", conn);
      command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PROC_PARAMETRO", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = 100;
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PROC_PARAMETRO1", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = 'valor';
      conn.Open();
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

Alguns detalhes com relação a execução da procedure são:
Você pode atribuir o resultado de uma procedure em uma variável:

```
var returnValue = command.ExecuteReader(); //Retorna a linha que foi executada
```

Pegando os valores retornados:

```
string variavel = "";
while (returnValue.Read())
{
    variavel = returnValue["COLUNA_TABELA"].ToString();
}
```